# How to read avro file with bytes schema using Avro C++ library

Tags: c++, avro

I have a avro file that doesn't have a JSON schema. All it has is a single field called "bytes" and the value is just binary representation of some object which I can decode. The first few bytes of the avro looks like;

```
bash-4.1$ hexdump -c ped.avro -n 32
0000000   O   b   j 001 002 026   a   v   r   o   .   s   c   h   e   m
0000010   a 016   "   b   y   t   e   s   "  \0   [ 346   Q 266 266 207
```

Anyone familiar with Avro C or Avro C++ libraries, can answer how to read these bytes field?

Avro C: http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.7/api/c/index.html
Avro C++: http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.5/api/cpp/html/

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any way to read AVRO data with the AVRO C or C++ libraries if you have no schema.  AVRO is always supposed to have a schema and without it there are any number of possible schemas that could fit the data.

Comment: Right. When I say no schema I mean no user provided schema. It is actually using bytes schema. I'll revise the question.